# Creating URLs containing the locale in Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, routes, twig, symfony4

I am creating a Symfony 4 web app that supports multiple languages. The routing is done, so I can have `/en/suchpage` or `/de/suchpage`. I am now looking for a way to link to "suchpage" using the right locale.

Routing looks as follows:

```
suchpage:
    path: /{_locale}/suchpage/
    controller: App\Controller\SimplePageController::such
    requirements:
        maw: '%app.locales%'
    defaults:
        _locale: '%locale%'
```

I am using Twig, and it is from Twig templates that I need to be able to link to the right version of a page. This "works":

```
{{ path('suchpage', {'_locale': app.request.locale}) }}
```

It has two issues though:

1. I do not want to be repeating this all over the place. Something like `{{ page('suchpage') }}` would be much better. Does a function like this exist? Can `path()` be made to behave like this?
2. This fails if the locale was not specified in the request, as can happen, since it is not required on all pages (since some have a default).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a maintened bundle, **JMSI18nRoutingBundle**, to achieve what you need.

`composer require jms/i18n-routing-bundle`

Some usefull links about this bundle :

Packagist : https://packagist.org/packages/jms/i18n-routing-bundle

GitHub : https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle

Comment: Generally, links to a tool or library [should be accompanied by usage notes, a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, or some sample code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605/584192), or if possible all of the above.